# <not computed> on collection output in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

When I tried to println `MapView` I have been got a message `MapView(<not computed>)`

```
val phonebook = Map("Jim" -> 555, "Daniel" -> 789)
println(phonebook)           // Map(Jim -> 555, Daniel -> 789)

val filteredMap = phonebook.filterKeys(_.startsWith("J"))
println(filteredMap("Jim"))  // 555
println(filteredMap)         // MapView(<not computed>)
```

If I defined `filteredMap` as following

```
val filteredMap = phonebook.view.filterKeys(_.startsWith("J"))
```

then nothing have been changed. Scala version is `2.13.2`

Why mapview cannot be printed and what is the best way to fix it?

Comment: Because **Views** are lazy collections, intended to be used as an optimization. The simplest way to fix it, is to force the view into a strict map: `phonebook.view.filterKeys(_.startsWith("J")).toMap`

Comment: just do .toMap and it will work you will be able to see as @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez mentioned

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `.toMap` to convert your mapView into a static map. As suggested by **@ Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez**

```
val filteredMap = phonebook.view.filterKeys(_.startsWith("J")).toMap
```